# Should I temporarily disable foreign key constraints? How?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

```
person:
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(64) not null

task:
    tenant_id   integer not null references person (id) on delete cascade,
    customer_id integer not null references person (id) on delete restrict
```

(They have a lot more columns than that, but the rest aren't relevant to the question.)

The problem is, I want to cascade-delete a `task` when its tenant `person` is deleted. But when the tenant and the customer are the same person, the `customer_id` foreign key constraint will restrict deletion.

My question has two parts:

1. Is temporarily disabling the second foreign key my only option?
2. If so, then how do I do that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: the table person is self referenced? or I did misunderstood?

Comment: @Frederic yes, I forgot... I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: @clapas, just got the problem when id = tenant_id? or with any other register that should be deleted on cascade? Sorry, I am realy not sure about Postgres, but got a similar problem with Ms sql-server, the sql-server dont alow to set on delete cascade when is self referenced... I did a cte to get all regs that would be deleted on cascade and deleted all on same delete statement.. in this way the FK didnt restrict cause does register would be deleted together...

Comment: Please clarify the role of `person.tenant_id`. Seems irrelevant for the question? Also, you speak of a first and a second part of the question, which I cannot identify. I see a single question. And declare the version of Postgres in use.

Comment: If you want to cascade deletes, why do you have `on delete restrict` on the `customer_id` foreign key constraint? Ah, I see, nevermind.

Comment: @Frederic The problem is only when id = tenand_id and the delete constraints in `task` table are not self-referencing, they refer to `person` table. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter if you follow the conversation you can read that I added the `tenant_id` column to table `person` because @Frederic asked about it. That try seems now lost, so I take it out again to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am using Postgres 9.1.6

Comment: More about disabling FKs https://stackoverflow.com/q/38112379/10245

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Effectively you create a *race condition* with contradicting rules.

My first impulse was to check whether a [`DEFERRED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) constraint would help. But it makes sense that it *doesn't make any difference.*

I found that the FK constraint that comes **first in the `CREATE TABLE`** script is the winner of this race. If the `ON DELETE CASCADE` comes first, the delete is cascaded, if `ON DELETE RESTRICT` comes first, the operation is aborted.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=afad77f6a453903ac0f4e674991aeb7a)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/09465/5)</sub>

This seems to correlate with a smaller `oid` in the catalog table [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html):

```
SELECT oid, * FROM pg_constraint WHERE conrelid = 'task'::regclass
```

But your feedback indicates, this is not the cause. Maybe [`pg_attribute.attnum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) decides the race. Either way, as long as it is not documented behavior you cannot rely on it to stay that way in the next major version. Might be worth to post a question on pgsql-general@postgresql.org.

Independent from all that, you need to consider other rows: even if `CASCADE` would go through for a row in `task` that has both `tenant_id` and `customer_id` pointing to a `person`, it will still be restricted if any row has only `customer_id` referencing `person`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=84ba89956117969cada116db226b6667)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f9e67/1)</sub>

#### How to disable the constraint?

Your best bet is to drop and recreate it. Do it all inside a transaction to make sure you don't corrupt referential integrity.

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE task DROP CONSTRAINT task_customer_id_fkey;

DELETE FROM person WHERE id = 3;

ALTER TABLE task ADD CONSTRAINT task_customer_id_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES person (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT;

COMMIT;
```

This locks the table exclusively and is not fit for routine use in a multi-user environment.

How did I know the *name* of the constraint? I took it from `pg_constraint` as demonstrated above. Might be easier to use an explicit constraint name to begin with:

```
CREATE TABLE task (
  customer_id integer NOT NULL
, tenant_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES person (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
, CONSTRAINT task_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
  REFERENCES person (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

#### Disable trigger?

There is also:

```
ALTER TABLE task DISABLE trigger ALL;
```

[More in the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html). But that would disable *all* triggers. I had no luck trying to disable only the trigger created by the system to implement a single FK constraint. Targeting a specific trigger is not implemented for *internal* triggers.

Other alternatives would be to implement your regime with [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) or [rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html). That would work just fine, but those are not enforced as strictly as foreign keys.

Comment: I already tried something similar and, for some reason, it didn't work. I had droped `tenant_id` foreign key and recreated it afterwards, so its oid is bigger (I can tell with the select from `pg_constraint` that you pointed out). I copied the code from your fiddle and it works locally, so this can be a way to achieve my goal, but I think the reason why it works could other than the oid being bigger. I have to try the `DEFERRED` thing. I don't understand the last part of your answer: both `tenant_id` and `customer_id` have `not null` constraints.

Comment: Ahh! Now I understand what you mean! The scenario in the second sqlfiddle does not happen in my system, because different tenants cannot share a common customer, i.e. the tenant defines a scope. My bad not mentioning it. I guess it is better to not rely on an undocumented behavior, as you say, so I will temporarily disable constraints or implement the solution with triggers or rules, I have not decided it yet. Anyway, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: By the way, I read in the create table section in the Postgres manual that "Referential actions other than the NO ACTION check cannot be deferred, even if the constraint is declared deferrable."

Comment: @clapas: I am aware of that and ran my tests with `NO ACTION` which would have served well as replacement for `RESTRICT`, but to no avail as documented in my answer.

Comment: Why have you deleted your comments? Now it's a senseless monologue.

Comment: @clapas: Sorry, I don't remember. Was too long ago. You can remove comments that are not helpful any more.