# Disable PostgreSQL foreign key checks for migrations

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a lot of migrations that have foreign keys in PostgreSQL 9.4.

This is creating a headache because the tables must all be in the exact order expected by the foreign keys when they are migrated. It gets even stickier if I have to run migrations from other packages that my new migrations depend on for a foreign key.

In MySQL, I can simplify this by simply adding `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` to the top of my migration file. How can I do this temporarily in PostgresSQL only for the length of the migration code?

BTW, using the Laravel Schema Builder for this.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't support any configuration option, but there is another possibility.

```
postgres=# \d b
        Table "public.b"
┌────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ Column │  Type   │ Modifiers │
╞════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ id     │ integer │           │
└────────┴─────────┴───────────┘
Foreign-key constraints:
    "b_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES a(id) DEFERRABLE
```

The referential integrity in Postgres is implemented by triggers, and you can disable triggers on table. With this method you can upload any data (risk), but it is significantly faster - because the check over large data is expensive. And if your upload is safe, then you can do it.

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE b DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
-- now the RI over table b is disabled
ALTER TABLE b ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
COMMIT;
```

Next possibility is using deferred constraints. This move constraint check to commit time. So you should not to respect order with `INSERT` commands:

```
ALTER TABLE b ALTER CONSTRAINT b_id_fkey DEFERRABLE;

BEGIN
postgres=# SET CONSTRAINTS b_id_fkey DEFERRED;
SET CONSTRAINTS
postgres=# INSERT INTO b VALUES(100); -- this is not in a table
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO b VALUES(10);
INSERT 0 1 
postgres=# COMMIT;
ERROR:  insert or update on table "b" violates foreign key constraint "b_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(100) is not present in table "a".
```

This method should be preferred for you, because the inserted data will be checked.

Comment: For some reason, this worked once for me and then not at all.  I'm in aws aurora postgres, where they lock down the `super user` role so customers can't mess up the replication settings. It looks like I have to be a super user to disable some system triggers. (I'm currently using my admin account that is also the owner-- I'm not sure why it worked once.)  Setting the replication option is also not a viable option, as that also requires the `super user` role.  My only option seems to be dropping and recreating the foreign keys...

Comment: Same here. Doing `DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` thing, but it has no effect. I don't even get any warning. It's just ignored.

Comment: On Amazon RDS, this gives the following error:
>  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_23031" is a system trigger
so this recipe is not for every case, unfortunately :)

Comment: Error on local db too. With user having all privileges to database, got **permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_16564" is a system trigger **

Comment: Does deferring the constraints until the COMMIT significantly improve the speed compared to checking the constraints while INSERTing? Would this still be the case using COPY rather than INSERT?

Comment: @otocan - no, not yet. The performance is same. Theoretically it can be implemented differently, but nobody did this work.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE b DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;`: `ERROR: permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_107616" is a system trigger`. You need to be a superuser to disable “system triggers” on a table: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371930/1760643

Answer (score 319):

For migration, it is easier to disable all triggers with:

```
SET session_replication_role = 'replica';
```

And after migration reenable all with

```
SET session_replication_role = 'origin';
```

Comment: Holy cow, is this both more simple and more appropriate for the specific task at hand. (Yes.)

Comment: Word of caution: this requires superuser privileges.  Try "SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED".

Comment: I'm on `10.4` and this above statement doesn't seem to work.

Comment: According to the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SESSION-REPLICATION-ROLE "origin" is the default enum value

Comment: By far the best answer! Incredible! Easy, straight forward, and it works!!

Comment: Would somebody be able to outline the dangers/risks of this method and in what scenarios it should be used and how to mitigate risks? What is best practice if this is considered a poor practice?

Comment: Btw, this parameter can be set in AWS RDS in the database parameter group and applied without restarting the db! Very useful if you're using DMS into an empty db with existing schema and constraints created.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Cuts runtime to only a fraction.

Comment: A very easy and convenient way to do perform the migration of large database

Comment: Maybe worth adding that this setting doesn't affect `truncate` operations (at least on postgres 13) which will still fail on foreign key constraint violations.

Comment: This is better approach

Comment: JJC's solution has worked for me as my user is not superuser. To rollback the option you've set simply execute "SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE;".

Comment: Really speeds up the speed, but i ran into an issue where some of my constraints didn't turn back on. I now have rows with FK that point to inexistant ids