# How to disable foreign keys constraints in postgresql during Laravel Testing

Tags: laravel, postgresql, testing, laravel-5.8

I have a lot of unit tests with many factories. But due to foreign keys I need even more factories in each test.

Is it possible to disable foreign keys during testing? I tried to use 'foreign_key_constraints' => false, but there are no effects.

```
    'pgsql_testing' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_TESTING', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_TESTING', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_TESTING', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_TESTING', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_TESTING', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => false, //does not help
    ],
```

I also tried use disableForeignKeyConstraints in setUp method

```
    protected function setUp() : void
{
    parent::setUp();
    Schema::connection('pgsql_testing')->disableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

I use PostgreSQL 10.7 and Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

The `disableForeignKeyConstraints();` function with the **PostgreSQL** driver send this command to the database server:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
```

As per [Postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html) `DEFERRED constraints` are not checked per statement but they are still checked when the transaction commit, so they are still checked.

I don't think it is the exact behaviour you want by calling the  `disableForeignKeyConstraints()` function.

But you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112379/disable-postgresql-foreign-key-checks-for-migrations) if it helps you to disable foreign key constrain in postgreSQL.