# Postgres: DELETE hangs on a table with a self-referential foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, freeze, self-reference

I am trying to delete rows from a table that has a self-referential foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id        SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES refers(id)
);
```

Now when I simply do:

```
DELETE FROM items;
```

the query freezes forever.
If I kill it with Ctrl-C, it says

> ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
>   CONTEXT: SQL statement "UPDATE ONLY "public"."items" SET "parent" = NULL WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "parent""

How to delete rows from such a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112379/disable-postgresql-foreign-key-checks-for-migrations), foreign keys in Postgres are implemented as triggers, so you can temporarily disable foreign key checks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE items DISABLE TRIGGER ALL; 
DELETE FROM items; 
ALTER TABLE items ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Comment: Please post a [mre] for debug help. By the way your table Items does not contain a self-reference , The column foreign key parent_id references the table refer not item. Also if you actually want a self reference in a table be extremely cautious of not null for the child column. That forces an entry to be its own parent. IMHO not a good design.

Comment: there's no way to post a minimal example. The freeze was not a deadlock; it was a very very long operation)