# Merge multiple inserts into one to avoid violating foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

My database schema is as follows. I wanted to add all data at once with one transaction, but I don't think multiple inserts one after another would work as that would violate foreign keys. Is there a way to update it somehow? For example insert if not present and return id for next insert.

Here is what I have right now:

```
INSERT INTO accounts
(id, screen_name, "name", description, followers_count, friends_count, statuses_count)
VALUES(0, '', '', '', 0, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO countries
(id, code, "name")
VALUES(0, '', '');
INSERT INTO hashtags
(id, value)
VALUES(0, '');
INSERT INTO tweet_hashtags
(id, hashtag_id, tweet_id)
VALUES(0, 0, '');
INSERT INTO tweet_mentions
(id, account_id, tweet_id)
VALUES(0, 0, '');
INSERT INTO tweets
(id, "content", "location", retweet_count, favourite_count, happened_at, author_id, country_id, parent_id)
VALUES('', '', ?, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, '');
```

I was thinking about starting from outermost tables and then meet at tweet and accounts. Because my usecase is that I have a large JSON array and I want to insert some of the fields into database

Here is sample json object

```
{
   "created_at":"Sat Aug 01 01:59:59 +0000 2020",
   "id":1289380322899980288,
   "id_str":"1289380322899980288",
   "full_text":"RT @ginadivittorio: Still waiting",
   "truncated":false,
   "display_text_range":[
      0,
      77
   ],
   "entities":{
      "hashtags":[
         
      ],
      "symbols":[
         
      ],
      "user_mentions":[
         {
            "screen_name":"ginadivittorio",
            "name":"G. L. DiVittorio",
            "id":316229447,
            "id_str":"316229447",
            "indices":[
               3,
               18
            ]
         }
      ],
      "urls":[
         
      ]
   },
   "source":"",
   "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
   "user":{
      "id":969009630516076545,
      "id_str":"969009630516076545",
      "name":"M i k \u2661",
      "screen_name":"miksomar",
      "location":"Somewhere in Texas ",
      "description":"I hate it",
      "url":null,
      "entities":{
         "description":{
            "urls":[
               
            ]
         }
      },
      "protected":false,
      "followers_count":63,
      "friends_count":272,
      "listed_count":0,
      "created_at":"Thu Mar 01 00:41:14 +0000 2018",
      "favourites_count":18043,
      "utc_offset":null,
      "time_zone":null,
      "geo_enabled":false,
      "verified":false,
      "statuses_count":3028,
      "lang":null,
      "contributors_enabled":false,
      "is_translator":false,
      "is_translation_enabled":false,
      "profile_background_color":"000000",
      "profile_background_image_url":"",
      "profile_background_image_url_https":"",
      "profile_background_tile":false,
      "profile_image_url":"",
      "profile_image_url_https":"",
      "profile_banner_url":"",
      "profile_image_extensions_alt_text":null,
      "profile_banner_extensions_alt_text":null,
      "profile_link_color":"E81C4F",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000",
      "profile_text_color":"000000",
      "profile_use_background_image":false,
      "has_extended_profile":false,
      "default_profile":false,
      "default_profile_image":false,
      "following":false,
      "follow_request_sent":false,
      "notifications":false,
      "translator_type":"none"
   },
   "geo":null,
   "coordinates":null,
   "place":null,
   "contributors":null,
   "retweeted_status":{
      "created_at":"Sat Aug 01 01:36:28 +0000 2020",
      "id":1289374404179263488,
      "id_str":"1289374404179263488",
      "full_text":"Still waiting on the coronavirus check in text from my ex",
      "truncated":false,
      "display_text_range":[
         0,
         57
      ],
      "entities":{
         "hashtags":[
            
         ],
         "symbols":[
            
         ],
         "user_mentions":[
            
         ],
         "urls":[
            
         ]
      },
      "source":"",
      "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
      "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
      "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
      "user":{
         "id":316229447,
         "id_str":"316229447",
         "name":"G. L. DiVittorio",
         "screen_name":"ginadivittorio",
         "location":"",
         "description":"",
         "url":"",
         "entities":{
            "url":{
               "urls":[
                  {
                     "url":"",
                     "expanded_url":"",
                     "display_url":"Instagram.com/ginadivittorio",
                     "indices":[
                        0,
                        23
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "description":{
               "urls":[
                  {
                     "url":"",
                     "expanded_url":"",
                     "display_url":"",
                     "indices":[
                        0,
                        23
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "protected":false,
         "followers_count":63213,
         "friends_count":752,
         "listed_count":106,
         "created_at":"Mon Jun 13 04:02:16 +0000 2011",
         "favourites_count":15599,
         "utc_offset":null,
         "time_zone":null,
         "geo_enabled":true,
         "verified":false,
         "statuses_count":7283,
         "lang":null,
         "contributors_enabled":false,
         "is_translator":false,
         "is_translation_enabled":false,
         "profile_background_color":"C0DEED",
         "profile_background_image_url":"",
         "profile_background_image_url_https":"",
         "profile_background_tile":true,
         "profile_image_url":"",
         "profile_image_url_https":"",
         "profile_banner_url":"",
         "profile_image_extensions_alt_text":null,
         "profile_banner_extensions_alt_text":null,
         "profile_link_color":"7FDBB6",
         "profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF",
         "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6",
         "profile_text_color":"333333",
         "profile_use_background_image":true,
         "has_extended_profile":true,
         "default_profile":false,
         "default_profile_image":false,
         "following":false,
         "follow_request_sent":false,
         "notifications":false,
         "translator_type":"none"
      },
      "geo":null,
      "coordinates":null,
      "place":null,
      "contributors":null,
      "is_quote_status":false,
      "retweet_count":21,
      "favorite_count":455,
      "favorited":false,
      "retweeted":false,
      "lang":"en"
   },
   "is_quote_status":false,
   "retweet_count":21,
   "favorite_count":0,
   "favorited":false,
   "retweeted":false,
   "lang":"en"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112379/disable-postgresql-foreign-key-checks-for-migrations might be an alternative.

Comment: Hello, I am not trying to migrate the database, I am looking for a way to write correct inserts

Comment: "I wanted to add all data at once" sounds migrate-ish...

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an example of one of the json records from the array?

Comment: Use CTE's: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html. See 7.8.2. Data-Modifying Statements in WITH