# How to Initialise & Populate a Postgres Database with Circular ForeignKeys in SQLModel?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, sqlmodel

Goal:
I'm trying to use [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) (a wrapper that ties together `pydantic` and `sqlalchemy`) to define and interact with the back-end database for a cleaning company. Specifically, trying to model a system where customers can have multiple properties that need to be cleaned and each customer has a single lead person who has a single mailing property (to contact them at). Ideally, I want to be able to use a single table for the mailing properties and cleaning properties (as in most instances they will be the same).

Constraints:

- Customers can be either individual people or organisations
- A lead person must be identifiable for each customer
- Each person must be matched to a property (so that their mailing address can be identified)
- A single customer can have multiple properties attached to them (e.g. for a landlord that includes cleaning as part of the rent)

The issue is that the foreign keys have a circular dependency.

- Customer -> Person based on the `lead_person_id`
- Person -> Property based on the `mailing_property_id`
- Property -> Customer based on the `occupant_customer_id`

[image]

Code to reproduce the issue:

```py
# Imports
from typing import Optional, List
from sqlmodel import Session, Field, SQLModel, Relationship, create_engine
import uuid as uuid_pkg


# Defining schemas
class Person(SQLModel, table=True):
    person_id: uuid_pkg.UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid_pkg.uuid4, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=True)
    first_names: str
    last_name: str
    mailing_property_id: uuid_pkg.UUID = Field(foreign_key='property.property_id')
    customer: Optional['Customer'] = Relationship(back_populates='lead_person')
    mailing_property: Optional['Property'] = Relationship(back_populates='person')

class Customer(SQLModel, table=True):
    customer_id: uuid_pkg.UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid_pkg.uuid4, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=True)
    lead_person_id: uuid_pkg.UUID = Field(foreign_key='person.person_id')
    contract_type: str
    lead_person: Optional['Person'] = Relationship(back_populates='customer')
    contracted_properties: Optional[List['Property']] = Relationship(back_populates='occupant_customer')
    
class Property(SQLModel, table=True):
    property_id: uuid_pkg.UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid_pkg.uuid4, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=True)
    occupant_customer_id: uuid_pkg.UUID = Field(foreign_key='customer.customer_id')
    address: str
    person: Optional['Person'] = Relationship(back_populates='mailing_property')
    occupant_customer: Optional['Customer'] = Relationship(back_populates='contracted_properties')
    

# Initialising the database
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_URL}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}')
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


# Defining the database entries
john = Person(
    person_id = 'eb7a0f5d-e09b-4b36-8e15-e9541ea7bd6e',
    first_names = 'John',
    last_name = 'Smith',
    mailing_property_id = '4d6aed8d-d1a2-4152-ae4b-662baddcbef4'
)

johns_lettings = Customer(
    customer_id = 'cb58199b-d7cf-4d94-a4ba-e7bb32f1cda4',
    lead_person_id = 'eb7a0f5d-e09b-4b36-8e15-e9541ea7bd6e',
    contract_type = 'Landlord Premium'
)

johns_property_1 = Property(
    property_id = '4d6aed8d-d1a2-4152-ae4b-662baddcbef4',
    occupant_customer_id = 'cb58199b-d7cf-4d94-a4ba-e7bb32f1cda4',
    address = '123 High Street'
)

johns_property_2 = Property(
    property_id = '2ac15ac9-9ab3-4a7c-80ad-961dd565ab0a',
    occupant_customer_id = 'cb58199b-d7cf-4d94-a4ba-e7bb32f1cda4',
    address = '456 High Street'
)


# Committing the database entries
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(john)
    session.add(johns_lettings)
    session.add(johns_property_1)
    session.add(johns_property_2)
    session.commit()
```

Results in:

```
ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "customer" violates foreign key constraint "customer_lead_person_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (lead_person_id)=(eb7a0f5d-e09b-4b36-8e15-e9541ea7bd6e) is not present in table "person".
```

This issue is specific to Postgres, which unlike SQLite (used in the docs) imposes constraints on foreign keys when data is being added. I.e. replacing `engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_URL}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}')` with `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')` will let the database be initialised without causing an error - however my use-case is with a Postgres DB.

Attempted Solutions:

- Used link tables between customers/people and properties/customers - no luck
- Used `Session.exec` with [this code from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204024/8035710) to temporarily remove foreign key constraints then add them back on - no luck
- Used primary joins instead of foreign keys as described in [this SQLModel Issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/10#issuecomment-1002835506) - no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable PostgreSQL foreign key checks for migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112379/disable-postgresql-foreign-key-checks-for-migrations)

Comment: Thanks I tried that solution with both `SET session_replication_role = 'replica';` and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` to no avail