# PostgreSQL: Disabling foreign key checks - laravel migrations

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm switching to PostgreSQL and i need to disable the foreign key check for one of my migrations.
I'm getting relation [table name] does not exist error and  none of the following works:

```
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        //...
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

```
        \DB::statement('SET session_replication_role = \'replica\';');
        //...
        \DB::statement('SET session_replication_role = \'origin\';');
```

```
        \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tenants DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;');
        //..
        \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tenants Enable TRIGGER ALL;');
```

I'm using:
Postgres v15 /
PHP v8.2.5 /
laravel v10 /
wamp on Windows 11

Example of Usage:

```
        Schema::create('tenants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->integer('is_trial')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(0);
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('plan_id')->nullable()->index('plan_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->json('data')->nullable();
        });


        \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tenants DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;');

        Schema::table('tenants',function (Blueprint $table) {
         
            $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('plans')->deferrable(true); //->onDelete('cascade');
            
        });

        \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tenants Enable TRIGGER ALL;');
```

Comment: related post I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112379/disable-postgresql-foreign-key-checks-for-migrations

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an inadequate problem description.

Comment: @jian I've already seen and tried that one. Still getting the error.

Comment: If you get that error message with the second of the techniques you are showing, the problem is in the `...` (the SQL statements in between).