# Efficient approach to remove the majority of rows from a PostgreSQL table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration, sql-delete, postgresql-performance

I have a table in my Postgres database with approximately 4 million rows, and I need to reduce it to around 30,000 rows while preserving the original IDs due to foreign key references. The condition for deletion is based on a column named **is_X**, and rows where this column is **false** should be removed. Note: I'm using Ruby on Rails.

I'm looking for the most efficient approach to accomplish this without causing excessive performance degradation & maintenance breaks. Here are some options I'm considering:

1. **Copy-Delete-Copy Back** Create a temporary table, copy the rows that meet the condition to the temporary table, truncate the original table, and then copy the rows back. Currently this seems to be the best fit for my problem. But I want to investigate further about what could go wrong. Since my table has several indexes, foreign keys.
2. **Maintenance Task** Use a database maintenance task or job to gradually delete rows in chunks to reduce the impact on performance. However, I'm concerned about the time it may take.
3. **Direct Deletion** Delete the rows directly from the table using a single SQL DELETE statement. While this might be straightforward, I'm unsure about the potential performance issues with a table of this size.

I'm looking for advice on which approach would be the fastest and most efficient in terms of both execution time and database performance. If there are other alternative methods I haven't considered, please share them as well.

Any insights, best practices, or code examples to accomplish this task efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

I haven't finalized any of them due to uncertainties about their efficiency and potential drawbacks.

Comment: 4 million is just a number, not even a large one, it doesn't say anything about size. If each record would by 1kB, your entire table would be just 3.8GB. My phone has more RAM available...

Comment: @FrankHeikens I guess it's less than 1GB, so do you imply that just deleting would do the job since its relatively small data ?

Comment: Yes, I would keep it simple and just use a plain simple DELETE. You might want to run VACUUM FULL afterwards and a REINDEX to optimize storage and the indexes.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1

For the given cardinalities, typically fastest overall in your list by a long shot - **if** it actually is an option. You need the necessary privileges to `TRUNCATE` the table. And the mentioned FK constraints raise an exception while any row in the truncated table is still referenced.

You *might* drop FK constraint(s), and later recreate:

```sql
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE other_tbl DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS some_name_fkey;
-- more?

CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_tmp AS
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE is_x IS NOT FALSE
-- ORDER BY ??  -- cluster while being at it?
;

TRUNCATE tbl;

INSERT INTO tbl SELECT * FROM tbl_tmp;

ALTER TABLE other_tbl
  ADD CONSTRAINT some_name_fkey FOREIGN KEY (col) REFERENCES tbl(col);
-- more?

COMMIT;
```

If you involve a temporary table, make sure `temp_buffers` is set high enough to process it in RAM. See:

- [Best way to delete millions of rows by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290900/best-way-to-delete-millions-of-rows-by-id/8290958#8290958)

#### Option 4

But if you can do that, you may be able to create a new table right away, and drop the old one, skipping the temp table. Beware of other dependencies like views, etc.

```sql
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE tbl RENAME TO tbl_old;  -- to free up the name

CREATE TABLE tbl AS
SELECT * FROM tbl_old WHERE is_x IS NOT FALSE
-- ORDER BY ???  -- cluster while being at it?
;

-- comments, constraints, indexes etc.?

ALTER TABLE other_tbl
  DROP CONSTRAINT some_name_fkey  -- drop old
, ADD CONSTRAINT some_name_fkey FOREIGN KEY (col) REFERENCES tbl(col);
-- more?

DROP tbl_old;

COMMIT;
```

#### Option 5

With **superuser** privileges you might even disable all triggers in place (FK constraints are implemented with internally generated constraint triggers). Faster, but **more dangerous**. Unlike the first option, referential integrity is not checked when you enable the triggers again. So you better know exactly what you are doing lest you break things.

```sql
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE tbl DISABLE trigger ALL;  -- are you sure?

CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_tmp AS
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE is_x IS NOT FALSE
-- ORDER BY ???  -- cluster while being at it?
;

TRUNCATE tbl;

INSERT INTO tbl SELECT * FROM tbl_tmp;

ALTER TABLE tbl ENABLE trigger ALL;

COMMIT;
```

See:

- [Should I temporarily disable foreign key constraints? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006669/should-i-temporarily-disable-foreign-key-constraints-how/15009099#15009099)

#### Option 3

That said, for just a few million rows, it might be simplest and safest to just run the `DELETE`. Follow up with `VACUUM ANALYZE tbl`.
Or, just this once, if the exclusive lock is still ok, to compact table and indices:

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE tbl;
```

Comment: I guess I'll go with good old `DELETE`. After deleting, I'm planning to run `VACUUM`, but still not sure about the lock time if I use the `FULL` option. Since I'll do this on production, I'm trying to understand what's the best fit for me.

Comment: @bahri: Consider accepting the answer if this answers your question properly.